# Table[1] returning nil when table does exist and has values

Tags: arrays, indexing, lua, garrys-mod, source-engine

```
local mapSpawnsData = {}
local JSONData = file.Read(filePath)            -- read file as json text
mapSpawnsData = util.JSONToTable(JSONData)      -- convert JSON to table

print("TABLE:")
PrintTable(mapSpawnsData)
print("TABLE[1]:")
print(tostring(mapSpawnsData[1]))
```

This is a script for a game called garrysmod. [PrintTable()](https://wiki.facepunch.com/gmod/Global.PrintTable) is a function I can call included in the game.

The code snippet I included returns this: (Same output if I remove the tosring())

```
TABLE:
gm_construct:
            1       =       -1303.524902 167.472397 -44.081600
            2       =       1250.890137 331.746185 -44.081600
            3       =       674.012085 223.775604 -32.148102
TABLE[1]:
nil
```

I expected to get back "gm_construct". What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you didn't notice is that PrintTable printed `gm_construct:` first and then `1 =` .
That means the table actually contains only `gm_construct` key with a table with 3 keys.

To be able to always read PrintTable output properly look at the ident. `1 =`  is tabulated to the right once, this means they are keys of something nested in the table you initially printed.

If this still confuses you, try to run this:

```lua
for k,v in pairs(mapSpawnsData) do
    print(k, "=", v)
end
```

This won't print nested content.

To make your code work do `mapSpawnsData.gm_construct[1]` or `mapSpawnsData["gm_construct"][1]`

Comment: Thank you, this put me in the right direction.